# how to call a function of a javascript file from another javascript file without using HTML in titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

Hi I am building a iOS app using Appcelerator,

I have a file `app.js` and a file `webService.js`

the file webService.js contains a `function x`

now from my `app.js` file i want to call `function x` that is present in the `webService.js`
file.

I searched a lot but i only found that using html..i am not using any html in it, it is just pure javascript.

Comment: Don't all Appcelerator apps start with an index page? You could load webService.js there.

Comment: Include the file using Ti.include('webService.js); in app.js and call the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
Ti.include('path/file.js');
```

Answer (score 3):

Include the file in app.js using :

```
Ti.include('path/webService.js');
```

and call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use include, but i advise you to take a look at commonjs. 
Commonjs is the future on architecturing appcelerator's applications.

You should check [this](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium)

Answer (score 0):

`Ti.include` is deprecated since Titanium 3.3, and it doesn't work in my environment. If you are using coffee, try [coffee-concat](https://github.com/fairfieldt/coffeescript-concat) , though it's somehow ugly.